# How to remove the duplicate string completely from the list using pandas python?

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, set

I have a DataFrame as below:

```
index text_column

   0   ,(Unable_to_see),(concern_code),(concern_color),(Unable_to_see)
   1   ,Info_concern,Info_concern
   2   ,color_Concern,color_Concern,no_category
   3   ,reg_Concern,reg_Concern
```

I am trying to remove duplicates including the source value completely within each row.

I tried this:

```
df['result'] = [set(x) for x in df['text_column']]
```

This gives me a list of values without duplicates but with source value, I need the source value to be removed as well.

Desired output:

```
     result
    
  0  (concern_code),(concern_color)
  1  
  2  no_category
  3
```

Any suggestions or advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Version 1:  Removing duplicates across all rows:

You can use [`.drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) with parameter `keep=False` after splitting and expanding the substrings by [`.str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html).

Then, regroup the entries into their original rows by [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) on the row index (level 0).  Finally, aggregate and join back the substrings of the original same row with [`.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.aggregate.html) and `','.join`

```
df['result'] = (df['text_column'].str.split(',')
                                 .explode()
                                 .drop_duplicates(keep=False)
                                 .groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
               )
```

[`.drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) with parameter `keep=False` ensures to remove duplicates including the source value.

Alternatively, you can also do it with [`.stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) in place of [`.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html), as follows:

```
df['result'] = (df['text_column'].str.split(',', expand=True)
                                 .stack()
                                 .drop_duplicates(keep=False)
                                 .groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
               )
```

**Data Input:**

(Added extra test cases from the sample data in question:)

```
                                                      text_column
0  (Unable_to_see),(concern_code),(concern_color),(Unable_to_see)
1                                       Info_concern,Info_concern
2                         color_Concern,color_Concern,no_category
3                                         reg_Concern,reg_Concern
4                                                    ABCDEFGHIJKL
5                                                    ABCDEFGHIJKL
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

                                                      text_column                          result
0  (Unable_to_see),(concern_code),(concern_color),(Unable_to_see)  (concern_code),(concern_color)
1                                       Info_concern,Info_concern                             NaN
2                         color_Concern,color_Concern,no_category                     no_category
3                                         reg_Concern,reg_Concern                             NaN
4                                                    ABCDEFGHIJKL                             NaN
5                                                    ABCDEFGHIJKL                             NaN
```

***Note the last 2 rows with same strings are removed as duplicates even when they are in different rows.***

#### Version 2:  Removing duplicates within the same row only:

If the scope of removing duplicates is limited to only within the same row rather than across all rows, we can achieve this by the following code variation:

```
df['result'] = (df['text_column'].str.split(',', expand=True)
                                 .stack()
                                 .groupby(level=0)
                                 .agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.drop_duplicates(keep=False)))
               )
```

**Data Input:**

(Added extra test cases from the sample data in question:)

```
                                                      text_column
0  (Unable_to_see),(concern_code),(concern_color),(Unable_to_see)
1                                       Info_concern,Info_concern
2                         color_Concern,color_Concern,no_category
3                                         reg_Concern,reg_Concern
4                                                    ABCDEFGHIJKL
5                                                    ABCDEFGHIJKL
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)

                                                      text_column                          result
0  (Unable_to_see),(concern_code),(concern_color),(Unable_to_see)  (concern_code),(concern_color)
1                                       Info_concern,Info_concern                                
2                         color_Concern,color_Concern,no_category                     no_category
3                                         reg_Concern,reg_Concern                                
4                                                    ABCDEFGHIJKL                    ABCDEFGHIJKL
5                                                    ABCDEFGHIJKL                    ABCDEFGHIJKL
```

***Note the last 2 rows with same strings are kept since they are in different rows.***

Comment: Is there a way to implement this without explode()?

Comment: @code_learner  Any concern with explode() ?   This is the natural way to work with split strings one by one.  Without using it, we would need much more complicated way to do it.  May not actually save much with the complicated algorithm.

Comment: @code_learner  See my edit above.  Revised without using .explode().

Comment: Some how it does not work with the actual dataset that am dealing with. Works with the given example though. The problem is my given example values are unique but my dataset has duplicated values.

Comment: @code_learner  Note that the `str.split()` has slightly changed in this revised code.

Comment: @code_learner  Your given example values are unique ?  Are you sure ?  E.g. `(Unable_to_see)` in row 0 and `color_Concern` are duplicates, right ?

Comment: @code_learner  Please edit your question to give more accurate sample data if you think your sample data here cannot represent your real data.  Thanks.

Comment: @code_learner  And how is it related to the use or not use of `.explode()` ?   Note that we explode only in the intermediate steps, it will be later on re-grouped into original rows with the `groupby()` statement.  So, what's the real concern of it ?

Comment: I think stack() works for me the way it is expected to, really not sure why explode() wont work though. Appreciate your insights on this.

Comment: @code_learner  One more point to clarify with you.   Is the scope of dropping duplicates be limited to the same line, or across lines ?   If limited only to the same line, I think may be a little bit changes needed.

Comment: @code_learner  See my second edit above if you want to remove the duplicates only within the same row (rather than across all rows).

Comment: @code_learner  Whichever the version you use, remember to accept the solution if it works for you !

Comment: yes dropping duplicates was to be done to the same line only. With the previous solution, removing duplicates across the lines was actually giving me Nan's mostly. The updated solution works perfect. Thanks for clarifying the difference.